# If or since, does it make a difference?

Tags: word-usage, differences, clauses, common-word

In these sentences below, does it makes a difference if I replace *if* with *since*?

1）*If you are unemployed, why did you leave your last job?*
 2）*If you are innocent, why did you flee?*
 3）*If you are a Christian, why do you believe in a personal God like this?*

My questions:

1. Does *if* here suggest a hypothesis, which means anyone who speaks these words is not sure or does not admit the fact?
2. Does replacing *if* with *since* make the clause a fact rather than a hypothesis?
3. If replacing *if* with *since* does make a difference, can *if* still be used if the context can imply that the clause is indeed a fact?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: They are not interchangeable. Trust me on this.

Comment: Great question, +1)

Comment: I have never heard or seen a learner who confused [***if***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/if?s=t) with [***since***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/since?s=t) before. Do these words mean the same in your native tongue?

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A, no, they are two words and the difference is clear-cut.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I found 3 to be the interesting part of this question.  Being In a situation where you could replace `if` with `since` doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: @CandiedOrange the same could be said for 2. E.g.,  2.  *"Why did you run away, [seeing that](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/seeing-that) you're innocent?"*. 3. *"Why do you believe in gods, seeing (that) you are a Christian?"* And 1. could be rephrased as: *"Since you're complaining that you can't pay the bills, why did you leave your last job?"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does.

> 1）**Since** you are unemployed, why did you leave your last job?
>   2）**Since** you are innocent, why did you flee?
>   3）**Since** you are a Christian, why do you believe in a personal God like this?

Now these all assert something to be true, where before they only assumed something might be true.

> 1) Does if here suggest a hypothesis, which means anyone who speaks these words is not sure or does not admit the fact?

This is true only insofar as the use of `if` itself does not imply the fact.  It can be used in contexts where the fact has already been implied.  It's in those cases that a switch to `since` can be considered.  But that doesn't necessarily make use of `if` wrong.

"You say you're too busy to talk.  If that's true, why are you still talking about it?"

"You say you're too busy to talk.  Since that's true, why are you still talking about it?"

> 2) Does replacing "if" with "since" make the clause a fact rather than a hypothesis?

Yes.  `Since` should not be used unless asserting a fact.

> 3) If replacing "if" with "since" does make a difference, can "if"still be used if the context can imply that the clause is indeed a fact?

Yes. `If` can be used independent of knowledge of fact.  `If` can be used to indicate assumption of fact (hypothesis) or to lay out conditions used to select between options.

"If you are as short as we all know you are then you can't ride the rollercoaster"

Answer (score 0):

'Since' would be used when the condition is assumed to be surely true.
The other would be used to even question the condition.